# Pyplot: plotting SGDClassifer for text

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have classified a large dataset of text documents, such as in this [scikit-learn example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html). Now I am trying to now create a nice graph like [in this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_separating_hyperplane.html).

The problem is that my data is strings whereas that example has lists of numbers. Is there any way I can make a similar graph, perhaps using the frequency of the appearance of a word in a document?

My data is formatted just like the 20newsgroup data in the [first link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can only do scatter-plots in two dimensions. For text data, you usually have tens or hundreds of thousands of features.
What I sometimes do is visualize the large coefficients like [in this notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/amueller/pydata-strata-2015/blob/master/Chapter%206%20-%20Working%20With%20Text%20Data.ipynb):

The result will be a bar-plot that shows the sign and magnitude of the large coefficients.